# CyberStart Assess Challenge 11

Tags: javascript

In CyberStart Assess I can't complete challenge 11 and so would like some help
on challenge 11.

```
var flag = "o0xbEmnf";
var shift = 3;

var decrypt = function() {
    var alphaArray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        alphaArray.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arguments[i],10) + 97 - 1));
    }
    attemptDecrypt(alphaArray);
}
```

I'm not sure about what half of this means so I would appreciate some tips or if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Just to understand, when you say explain it to you, do you mean explain what the above lines of code means, or what it does? I guess we can explain what it means, but I'm not sure we can explain what the code does because there's just too little information.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Questions along the lines of "I want to do X; can someone tell me how to write my code?" are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please see [help/on-topic] for more details. Note that if your question is, "I want to do X and I tried approach Y but it didn't work; can anyone help me figure out what I did wrong?" then that question is on-topic on Stack Overflow, and you'll find many people willing to help you with your problem.

Comment: mainly what it means but if you have done challenge 11 you will know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Run the decrypt() function from the console with the parameters shown above the input box (e.g if it was 20;23;15 you'd run decrypt(20,23,15)).